# Filter folder and files into tree (composite pattern)

Tags: java, sorting, design-patterns, reflection, tree

I cannot create sort method to put folders and files into tree structure. I am using composite pattern, I have Leaf (File) and Node(Directory). And also I have a list of Entries. I cannot figure out how to elagantly to sort them and create tree structure.
Here is an example of output

```
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/osgi/is directory !
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/is directory !
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/selector/is directory !
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/tools/is directory !
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/is directory !
Log4j-config.xsd
Log4j-events.dtd
Log4j-events.xsd
Log4j-levels.xsd
META-INF/LICENSE
META-INF/log4j-provider.properties
META-INF/NOTICE
META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat
META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/AbstractLifeCycle.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/AbstractLogEvent.class
org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractAppender.class
```

I can determine in what directory put entry only by path. I have no idea how to do this correctly.
I have two classes (composite pattern) EntryFile and EntryFolder they both extends Entry, EntryFolder in turn has method to add Entry objects.
Please suggest how to do this. My brain doesn't want to work.
Thx in advance.

Comment: Use [`Files.walkFileTree()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it is "how can I go from a list of strings representing directories to a tree structure representing the file system".

Without providing all the code, I would think your solution should be structured something like the following:

```
class EntryFolder implements Entry {

    public void addEntryFromPath(String path) {
        addEntryFromPathComponents(Arrays.toList(path.split("/"));
    }

    private void addEntryFromPathComponents(List<String> pathComponents) {
        if (pathComponents.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        } else if (pathComponents.size() == 1) {
            addFileEntry(pathComponents.get());
        } else {
            DirectoryEntry child = getDirectoryEntry(pathComponents.get(0));
            if (child == null) {
                child = addDirectoryEntry(childName);
            }
            child.addEntryFromPathComponents(path.subList(0, path.size()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use this with `entries` declared as `List<String>` you would use the following:

```
FolderEntry root = entries.stream()
    .collect(EntryFolder::new, EntryFolder::addEntryFromPath);
```